# javascript - Keep matching regex in a string until there is no match

Tags: javascript, regex

> **TL;DR**
>   How can I search a string for a pattern and replace it with something that might result in the appearance of the pattern again, without a loop.

So I have this situation where I need to search some certain patterns in a string, which goes like this :

1. Look for **i.**`'(\-\-)+|(\+)+'` then **ii.**`(\+\-)+|(\-\+)+` in the whole string and replace **i.** with `+` and **ii.** with `-`.
2. Check again If the string is out of both **i.** and **ii.**, if yes, break, else, go to step 1.

This is what I tried (the string is `str`), and the problem with it is that it only searches through the string once, i.e:

```
var str = '1+-2--++--+4---++--+2';
str.replace(/(\-\-)+|(\+)+/g,'+').replace(/(\+\-)+|(\-\+)+/g,'-');
```

The string after the first replace (the `()` are there just to highlight the changes, they aren't part of the string) :

```
1(+)-2(--)(++)(--)(+)4(--)-(++)(--)(+)2 => 1(+)-2(+)(+)(+)(+)4(+)-(+)(+)(+)2
```

And after the second replace :

```
1(+-)2++++4(+-)+++2 => 1(-)2++++4(-)+++2
```

And that's it, but I'm not done yet, there are still appearances of `++++` and `-+`.
I want it to go on like this :

```
1-2(++++)4-(+++)2 => 1-2(+)4-(+)2
1-2(+)4(-+)2 => 1-2(+)4(-)2 => # and the final result 1-2+4-2
```

I know it could be done with a loop, but if there exists a better, easier and shorter way, I would appreciate it if someone points it out.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to get just the numbers?

Comment: @anubhava I edited the question, the output should be `1-2+4-2`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but if the parts that you have replaced in one replace-call can result again in parts which you are trying to remove, then you have to use some sort of a loop.

Comment: @andremcgruder, No I'm trying to get a minimum one `-` or `+` between each number under conditions that are explained in the question.

Comment: @ThomasD., exactly, but I don't want to do a loop, I want a regex way, If there is, if not, I guess I'm gonna have to be stuck with the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some analysis shows that an uninterrupted sequence of `+` and `-` will eventually be reduced to just one character (a `-` or `+`).

It seems like an algorithm to reduce sequences with an odd number of `-` to just one `-`, and to a `+` when there are an even number of them.

However, if that is indeed the desired behaviour, the second regular expression should not look to repetitions, but only replace one occurrence of an altering pair at a time, i.e. with `/(\+\-)|(\-\+)/g` instead of `/(\+\-)+|(\-\+)+/g`.

Then the only way to end up with `-` is when there are an odd number of them in the sequence, since the first replacement can only remove an even number of them, while the second replacement leaves the number of them unchanged. In all other cases the end result for one sequence will be `+`.

So... then this problem can be simplified to this:

```js
var str = '1+-2--++--+4---++--+2';

var repl = str.replace(/\b(?=[+-])\+*(-\+*-\+*)*\b/g, '+')
              .replace(/\b\+*-[+-]*/g, '-');

console.log(repl);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I hoped for, thanks for understanding the problem.

Comment: `'1+-++-2--++----+++-+4+-++-+---2'` becomes `"1+2-4-2"` but you wrote `"1+2-4+2"` as expected result

Comment: Indeed my answer is only correct if I can assume that the OP's second regex should have been `/(\+\-)|(\-\+)/g` instead of `/(\+\-)+|(\-\+)+/g`. Maybe I jumped to conclusions...

Comment: @anubhava Yeah I'm sorry I made a mistake there, it's `"1+2-4-2"`.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** *I realize this answer basically duplicates trincot's answer, but I had already written half of it and then walked away to lunch before his answer was posted and I don't like letting my effort go to waste, plus I explain different things slightly differently.*

The final result is entirely based on `-` count and there are two cases:

1. An Even number of `-`s (Zero included), replaced by `+`

   ```
   \+*(?:-\+*-\+*)*
   \+*              Zero or more '+'s
      (?:           Non-capturing group
         -            Exactly one '-'
          \+*         Zero or more '+'s
             -        Exactly one '-'
              \+*     Zero or more '+'s
                 )* Repeat capture group Zero or more times
   ```
2. An odd number of `-`s (Same pattern with at least one `-`), replaced by `-`

   ```
   \+*-\+*(?:-\+*-\+*)*
   ```

But, there are a few pitfalls here. The first regex matches an empty string, which is not something we want to replace with a +. We can solve this with a lookahead, which verifies that the string being tested matches a certain overall pattern without consuming the string.

```
(?=[+-]+)
(?=       Positive lookahead
   [+-]     Either or '+' or '-'
       +    One or more times
        ) Close positive lookahead (rest of regex goes after this)
```

It also is not forced to only consider the entire string of `[+-]+` in between two numbers, so the first regex could encounter a case such as:

```
1++--+-2
```

And find a matching string `++--+`, leaving you with

```
1+-2
```

For this, we can employ the word boundary `\b`, or capturing groups for numbers on the ends of the regex combined with back-references to those groups in the replacement group. We will use `\b` as it is the more simple, elegant and efficient solution.

`\b` is a special regex character which matches a zero length 'boundary' between word characters `\w` and non-word characters `\W`

> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character. [[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)]

```js
var str = '1+--+-2--++--+4---++--+2';

var repl = str.replace(/\b(?=[+-])\+*(-\+*-\+*)*\b/g, '+')
              .replace(/\b\+*-\+*(?:-\+*-\+*)*\b/g, '-');

console.log(repl);
```

**Shortcut**

I'm a believer in leaving code a bit more verbose, modular and self documenting, but if byte count of your code matters to you more the second regex can simply be replaced by

```
\b[+-]{2,}\b
```

because after running the first replacement, any string made of `+` and `-` greater than length one must be those not matched by the first regex, therefore they should be replaced by `-`

```js
var str = '1+--+-2--++--+4---++--+2';

var repl = str.replace(/\b(?=[+-])\+*(-\+*-\+*)*\b/g, '+')
              .replace(/\b[+-]{2,}\b\b/g, '-');

console.log(repl);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and for posting the answer, it really helped +1.

Answer (score 2):

***edit:*** fixed the regex for *negatives*.. works correctly now.

*(Fyi - Note that even though this is a single replace it uses a callback.

On the upside, it is still twice as fast as using a double replace.)*

I am going to save this for use next time as the regex is solid,
and I've see this asked before a few times.

---

This can be with a single replace call.

`\b(?:(?:\+|--)*(-(?!-)(?:\+|--)*)+|(?:\+|--)+)\b`

```
 \b 
 (?:
      (?: \+ | -- )*                # optional positives
      (                             # (1 start), Neg (agressive)
           -                             # - sign
           (?! - )                       # not followed by a -
           (?: \+ | -- )*                # optional positives
      )+                            # (1 end)
   |                              # or,
      (?:                           # Pos (passive)
           \+
        |  --
      )+
 )
 \b
```

```js
var str = ' 1+-2--++--+4---++--+2--6,,,,5--+--+5 ';

console.log(
   str.replace(/\b(?:(?:\+|--)*(-(?!-)(?:\+|--)*)+|(?:\+|--)+)\b/g,
          function(m, g1) {return g1 ? '-' : '+';})
 );
```

Output `1-2+4-2+6,,,,5+5`